# Automatic add record after refreshing page

Tags: database

I have on page only this code:

```
 get_header();

    global $title;
    global $wpdb;
    global $current_user;


    if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    } else { }
     include_once('home-sidebar.php'); 
 get_footer();
```

I would like to automatically add a record after refreshing the page.

Comment: sory, i change page template and now work realy strange too me.

Comment: Add what record? Why? Please explain what you are trying to do.